# avoid auto-killing activity in android

Tags: android, memory

I make an android application for an exhibition (device is on about 8 hours a day). 
I have an issue: the application quits after about between 30mn and one hour.
I force the screen not to go into sleep mode, and it works fine. 
But how could avoid the auto-killing app by android ? Is this beacause of the memory manager ?

Comment: Is this a service that is getting killed or something else?

Comment: it's the activity, it seems that it runs in background, the device is back at the home screen.

Comment: Activities don't run in the background; they're on the screen or they're not running at all. I'm guessing that your activity has died, probably of a fatal error (perhaps resource exhaustion?)  It would help if you could check your logcat output for clues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not in the foreground, Android can terminate your process at any point to free up memory to run other processes.

Hence, a typical solution for an app like yours is to make it be the home screen. That way, it's very unlikely to be in the background for long, if at all.

Comment: my app is a foregreound app: it's a visualisation of photos. android seems to put it in background after a while, I mean make it disappear…although the ddms monitoring tells me it's still on !

Comment: @user2216280: That shouldn't happen. Something has to cause the home screen (or something else) to come to the foreground. Again, one advantage of being the home screen is that Android would have no reason to move you to the background, unless somebody runs another app.

Comment: ok thanks ! How could I do that  ? 
here's what I have so far in the manifest :                         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: @user2216280: Replace `LAUNCHER` with `HOME`, and you're set. On the next press of the devices HOME button, you will get a chooser to choose which home screen you want -- choose yours and make it the default. Any future HOME press will bring up your activity. The catch is that you may need to build a "backdoor" in somewhere to allow people to get at the real home screen, to reach Settings and such. Getting to the original home screen is not tough (`ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_HOME` `Intent` and `createChooser()` to force the chooser), but you'll have to come up with the trigger mechanism.